# Big mistake caused - "Error: no such partition"

Tags: partitioning

I did a mistake after installing ubuntu as dual boot in my windows 10 operating system. Note that my windows is installed in BIOS legacy mode and so I did the same for Ubuntu. 
It installed succesfully and everything worked properly but I made a mistake.

When I logged in into windows I found 2 newly created drives (New Drive J and New Drive K). I thought they were unnecessary and formatted them. Then, using disk manager I made them intro free space and just extended the I drive with the free space.

This caused the following problem in startup :

"**error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode....
grub rescue**>"

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You can just redo the Ubuntu installation again. That will create new partitions, and reinstall grub.

Answer (score 0):

I am only repeating what has been hinted at in the comments.  There is only one answer.  Repeat the installation.  Legacy for both is fine.  Your old installation is gone forever.

Usually during an install grub or part of it gets stored in the boot partition.  That points to the grub on your Ubuntu Install.  Since that is now gone it goes to the dreaded rescue mode!